# What kind of data does the data type `Location` store?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am making a GPS app for android. I need to know the location of the user. What kind of data does location store in this :

`Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);`

I mean does it store the co-ordinates or the city name etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html), it contains:

> A data class representing a geographic location.
>
> A location can consist of a latitude, longitude, timestamp, and other
>   information such as bearing, altitude and velocity.
>
> All locations generated by the LocationManager are guaranteed to have
>   a valid latitude, longitude, and timestamp (both UTC time and elapsed
>   real-time since boot), all other parameters are optional.

So yes, you can use methods from that page which the device knows.

See the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class on how to look up the city.

Comment: Yes, Geocoder.getFromLocation() gives a list of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects which have the getCountryName() method. Read about said methods. Be warned that getFromLocation should be done in a background thread and the returned addresses may have null fields for things it does not know.

Comment: Can the county feed ever be null for usa?

Comment: Country should be very unlikely to be null.